# AngularJs xml two listBox

Tags: xml, angularjs

I want to do two listboxes with this xml. One of them have to list the value of Name1 and the other one have to list the value of Name2... But i can't do the listbox for which one have to list the value of Name2.

```xml
<RequestType>
    <FullName i:nil="true" />
    <Name1>Request of other equipment</Name1>
    <iId>11</iId>
    <iId1>3</iId1>
    <nameList>
        <RequestTypeList>
            <Name2>IT Equipment</Name2>
            <iId2>5</iId2>
        </RequestTypeList>
        <RequestTypeList>
            <Name2>Phone Equipment</Name2>
            <iId2>5</iId2>
        </RequestTypeList>
        <RequestTypeList>
            <Name2>Radio Equipment</Name2>
            <iId2>5</iId2>
        </RequestTypeList>
        <RequestTypeList>
            <Name2>Other</Name2>
            <iId2>5</iId2>
        </RequestTypeList>
    </nameList>
</RequestType>
```

AND MY HTML

```xml
<select ng-options="a.iId as a.Name1 for a in RTypes"></select>
```

Comment: That's not JSON, looks more like XML.

Comment: You might want to create a service to handle the XML-to-JSON conversion - using some [ready-made library for that purpose](https://code.google.com/p/x2js/source/browse/xml2json.js?r=ebaa2598910f0750ff8593a2b259074f52aa25b9) - to [transform the request](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Of course, someone had already written an [angular module for XML](https://github.com/johngeorgewright/angular-xml) which might help. Anyhow, before you go down that path and dive into the nitty gritty, I suggest you go [**back to basics**](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial).

Comment: I don't went to convert XML in JSON but just do a listbox with the value "Name2" i can't do the ng-options